# Laravel 9 - Error "index was not found. Are you sure the view exists and is a .blade.php file?"

Tags: php, laravel

*I'm new and not so familiar with the posting etiquette, please forgive me if I break any conventions or rules.*

To summarise my problem, I am receiving an error in Laravel 9 in which it says "are you sure the view exists and is a .blade php file?".

I'm following a tutorial from **2019** so I can only assume there have been changes since then which have left me with the error, especially as I've followed the course exactly.

I've searched on google and stackoverflow for answers but they all seem to be for previous versions of Laravel, and honestly I don't even really understand the explanations given.

My end goal is to have localhost:8000/profile/{username} and ""/p/{username} present the index.blade.view, however it says it cannot be found because the ProfilesController can't be located.

At this point I'm pretty confused so I'll post the relevant code snippets (let me know if more is needed) and hopefully I can make some progress here :) Thank-you in advance!

[Directory structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bLSPR.png)

**web.php**

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;


Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('welcome');
});

Auth::routes();

Route::get('/p/create', 'PostsController@create');

Route::get('/profile/{user}', [App\Http\Controllers\ProfilesController::class,'index'])->name('profile.show');
```

**Profiles Controller**

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;


use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Models\User;

class ProfilesController extends Controller
{
    public function index($user)
    {

    $user = User::findOrFail($user);

    return view('index',['user' => $user
    ]);
}
}
```

Thanks guys and gals!

Comment: The `view()` method isn't reactive to the Controller you're in. When you call `view('index')`, it's looking for the file `index.blade.php` in `resources/views`; nowhere else. If you move your `index.blade.php` file out of `layouts/profiles`, your code should work.

Comment: Ah-ha! That worked, thank-you! I imagine if I want to keep index.blade.php in layouts/profiles I could change 'view('index)' to 'view('profiles/index)' ? I will try in the meantime.

Comment: If you want to keep the **index.blade.php** in `views/layouts/profiles` you can specify the path using **dot notation** in the **view** helper like `view('layouts.profiles.index')`

Comment: I think `/` (slash-notation) works too, but `.` (dot-notation) is typically preferred. An easy way to avoid manually having to include `'layouts.profile'` in every view in a Controller, you can simply define something like `private $viewRoot = 'layouts.profile';`, then `return view("{$this->viewRoot}.index");` (replacing `.index` with the appropriate view name)

Comment: That's super handy to know. Appreciate your help @Tim Lewis